# Can the redis cli show me items waiting in queue?

Tags: redis, queue

I have a redis queue and node app that is inserting items into the queue. They are just JSON strings. I'm using the [bee-queue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue) npm package for this.

For the purposes of debugging, it would be nice if there was way to see the items currently in the queue waiting to be processed using the redis cli?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "bq:myqueue:waiting"
2) "bq:myqueue:jobs"
3) "bq:myqueue:id"
```

I can see there are items in there

```
127.0.0.1:6379> llen bq:myqueue:waiting
(integer) 2
```

but I can't seem to actually view them:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get bq:myqueue:waiting
(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

When I use `LRANGE` to list the data, I get this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> LRANGE bq:myqueue:waiting 0 3
1) "9"
2) "8"
3) "7"
```

Based on the data I'm seeing when using the node.js client to process these items, those are the ids that redis is assigning to the items in the queue, but it's not the JSON data I am actually putting in the queue.

Comment: Since the command `llen` returned a value (and not an error) that means that the item with your key is a [List](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) so you'll need to use the list commands to see what's inside. `GET`, `SET`, etc. won't work for a List (or most other data types). [`LRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/LRANGE) is your best bet, but you'll need the length of the list to use it. Going with your post, we'll assume the length is two: `LRANGE bq:myqueue:waiting 0 2` which means, "return the elements in the list `bq:myqueue:waiting`, start at element 0 and retrieve 2 elements"

Comment: Have a look at my update but that seems to return the ids of the items in the queue, not the actual data. Not sure if it matters, but I am using the npm package bee-queue to insert the items into the queue from a node app. I'm not inserting them manually using the redis-cli.

Comment: `LRANGE` returns the actual elements in the list, so I wonder if the elements in `bq:myqueue:waiting` reference indices in `bq:myqueue:jobs` or perhaps `bq:myqueue:id`.  So for example, if "9" in the `waiting` list is an index of something in the `jobs` list. You can use [`LINDEX`](https://redis.io/commands/lindex) to retrieve the item with a specific index, for example `LINDEX bq:myqueue:jobs 9`

Comment: It does make sense to do it this way since one list likely holds the actual data, and the others hold maybe job ids that mean something to the application, and then a sorted list (which the `waiting` list appears to be) holds the index of the actual job data in the order they should be worked. `jobs` and `ids` may not be LISTS either, so you can use the [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/TYPE) command to identify them.

Comment: Yeah I tried inspecting the other two keys (`:jobs` and `:ids`) using `LRANGE` and `LINDEX` but they both return `WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`. I'm starting to suspect that it's just not possible. If bee-queue supports looking at the queue items without actually processing them maybe I can write my own client.

Comment: what does `TYPE bq:myqueue:jobs` and `TYPE bq:myqueue:id` return? They might be sets, or sorted sets, so you'd use the S* commands for sets and Z* commands for sorted sets. Use `SMEMBERS bq:myqueue:jobs` if it's a `set` and `ZRANGE bq:myqueue:jobs -inf inf` if it's a `sorted set`.

Comment: Okay, it turns the `:jobs` object is a hash so you can use the commands given here https://redis.io/commands/hkeys such as `HGET` and `HGETALL`.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Adam Marshall had the right idea in checking the type. It turns out that `bq:myqueue:jobs` is a hash so you can use the [hash commands](https://redis.io/commands/hkeys) for exploring the contents. For example

```
127.0.0.1:6379> TYPE bq:myqueue:jobs
hash

127.0.0.1:6379> HGKEYS bq:myqueue:jobs
 1) "11"
 2) "9"
 3) "4"

127.0.0.1:6379> HGET bq:myqueue:jobs "4"
"{"data":{"a":1001, "b": "four"},"options":{"timestamp":1632162180724,"stacktraces":[]},"status":"created","progress":0}"

127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL bq:myqueue:jobs
 1) "11"
 2) "{"data":{"a":1, "b": "two"},"options":{"timestamp":1632162260037,"stacktraces":[]},"status":"created","progress":0}"
 3) "9"
 4) "{"data":{"a":99, "b": "three"},"options":{"timestamp":1632189454151,"stacktraces":[]},"status":"created","progress":0}"
 5) "4"
 6) "{"data":{"a":1001, "b": "four"},"options":{"timestamp":1632162180724,"stacktraces":[]},"status":"created","progress":0}"
```

The formatting leaves a bit to be desired but I think that basically works.